# TextView array to TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to use a `UITextView` to enter in information, which then moves the information into a `UITableView`.

[image: This is just an example of what i want it to look like.[1]]

I need it to update the tableview each time a new line has been added.

I thought i could create an array out of the information in the TextView and place it into a TableView but i cant seem to figure out how to do this.

With this it still doesn't populate the table with what i type in the 'UITextView'.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Can you please update your question with code so easily to slow your problem.

Comment: The question i am asking is the first stage of my project, the above image is just an example i made using an array and a textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First set the `delegate` property of the `UITextView` to your `viewController`. Then use `textViewDidChange` method to initialize your array--

in `ViewController.h` file-

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtView;
    @end
```

and in `ViewController.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    NSMutableArray *listArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.txtView.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];;

    return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return listArray.count;
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"Array-- %@",listArray);

    NSLog(@"Array Count-- %lu",(unsigned long)listArray.count);

    NSLog(@"Text-- %@",textView.text);

}
@end
```

Use `listArray` to show your data on `tableView`.

Comment: The data entered in the textview does not fill the tableview still.

Comment: have to add UITextViewDelegate in .h file- @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: also set delegate and datasource of your tableview to your viewController.

Comment: Still no luck, tableview just opens blank

Comment: can you share your code, so that i can clearly understand your problem. This code works fine according to your problem.

Comment: first time your tableview empty.. whenever you type something in uitextview tableview will reload and try to log your array i.e. list array in textViewDidChange for checking object are added or not.

Comment: Sure ill post it above in a moment.

Comment: your code looks fine. Have you tried to NSLog listArray values or count?

Comment: After adding NSLog it seems that nothing is happening. Which is very confusing.

Comment: Nothing comes out of listArray in textViewDidChange method? What value do you get when you NSLog textView.text?

Comment: I get array of string having muliple value if there is new line in textview string.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex I get a 'format string is not a string literal' warning. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: @Dev.RK What you just added is literally what i need.

Comment: When you NSLog the pure text from textView.text, you get a warning, but not in your console, but in the code itself right? What does the console output?

Comment: where is this warning appear. In cellForRowAtIndexPath or textViewDidChange method. change this line cell.textLabel.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; with cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: Nothing happens in the console.

Comment: @vype i'm not getting any kind of warning in above code.

Comment: @Dev.RK could you update your code to everything you added to make that work? also where did you put the NSLog?

Comment: please wait a moment i will check and update my answer with code.

Comment: i have updated my answer. I'm not getting any warning any place. This code works fine.

Comment: This is really strange but i still get nothing, The identifier is correct and so is everything although i still get the warning messages. And the tableview doesn't update.

Comment: @Dev.RK do i need to connect any other outlets or anyting in the storyboard?

Comment: try to add new uitextview to your viewcontroller, connect delegate of uitextview to your viewController. Similarly connect uitableview datasource and delegate once again to your viewcontroller don't change any uitextview proparties. I'm trying to figure out your problem.

Comment: you can also try this hold your uitextview text in string in textViewDidChange and put this line -- NSString *tempStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textView.text];
   
    listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[tempStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]]

Comment: may be this will help you. :)

Comment: Again nothing happens. Is there a way to share the file that you created?

Comment: right now i can't share file. I update my answer with full code of both file .h and .m

Comment: my pleasure friend:) If answer finds helpful then please mark it as accepted. So others can benefit too.. Thanks

Comment: I know im doing something wrong and your answer works i just need to figure out what. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with the text of textview using the following method :

```
NSString* string;
NSArray* array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:(nonnull NSString*)]
```

now you can create your tableview using the above array. whenever you want to update the table, you can call the following method :

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to look for new lines you can do something like this:

```
NSArray <NSString*> *components = [self.textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

If you implement the delegate methods of `UITextView` specifically to get notifications when the text content changes you can then update an array that feeds into your table view.

Also here's the code in Swift just because we should be thinking about it now.

```
let components: [String] = textView.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Comment: I prefer to use `.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet. newlineCharacterSet())`, but I'm allergic to hardcoded values.

Comment: Fair enough. That is definitely better.